# Bitbucket- Webhook returning 302

Tags: bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

I have a BitBucket Repository in the cloud, I have Sourcetree that pushes my code from my local machine to the BitBucket Repository. In the BitBucket Repository  I have setup a webhook that should push my changes to the production URL. My URL is 
https://myproduct.samples.com/ (This is a sample URL). When i go to the View Requests of my webhook its says

repo:push  302

I don't know what I am doing wrong. Please help me in this regard

Answer (score 0):

302 is the status code for a temporary redirect, and that status is coming from your production server. You'll need to check the logs of the production server, or review the details on the redirected webhook, to see where specifically it's redirecting you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In the body of the webhook it says

<html><head><title>Object moved</title></head><body>
<h2>Object moved to <a href="https://myproduct.samples.com/">here</a>.</h2>
</body></html>

Comment: Does your webhook include the trailing slash? Your server might be redirecting "https://myproduct.samples.com" (without the trailing slash) to "https://myproduct.samples.com/" (with the trailing slash). If that's the case, update the webhook to include the trailing slash.

Comment: Is that what the webhook is trying to use, though?

Comment: In the Add new webhook in the URL textbox, I entered this URL. This is the URL of my production site where i expect so see the changes

Comment: Any way there to help me out?

Comment: You need to check your server logs. I don't have any access to those.

Comment: I already checked my event logs on the server and there is nothing

Comment: Something there is sending the redirect. You need to have the new redirect location in the Bitbucket webhook.

Comment: How do a create a Webhook URL for my repository?

Comment: Any one there to help me out?